# Is it possible to "NOT commit changes if error"?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, datagridview, ms-access-2007

I'm getting a DataError in my DataGridView (bound in a MS Access database) when I change a "Long Integer" field to letters, **but still commits the change I make** after showing the error, inputting the letter in the cell.

How do I make the cell's value go back to its previous valid value which is a number?

Comment: Could you provide some of the code you are using to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by `still commits the change`? If the [context](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewdataerroreventargs.context(v=vs.110).aspx) of the data error contains `Commit`, then the error was thrown because it could **not** commit the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I've stated in my comment: If the context of the data error contains `Commit`, then the error was thrown because it could **not** commit the data.

Now, in your data error handler, call the grids `CancelEdit`.

Something like this:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_DataError(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.DataError
    If ((e.Context And DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit) = DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit) Then
        e.ThrowException = False
        Me.DataGridView1.CancelEdit()
    Else
        e.ThrowException = True
    End If
End Sub
```